# Map<String, List<String, Object>> add new list entry when key exists

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I got `Map<ID, Object>` when looping over the entries via `.entrySet().stream()`

I want to map it to `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>`

When using `toMap()` I change the ID of my initial map to a String (with a database call), but different ID's can return the same string so there can be duplicates. Is it possible if my key already exists in the toMap of my new map that I'm collecting, that my ObjectOne is added in a new list entry of my new map in the format of `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>` .

I tried stuff with `Collectors.groupingBy()` and `Collectors.mapping()` but not getting it to work, curious if there is a way to do this

What I got now is the following solution, but I would like to collect it to map without having to define it first:

```
  Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> giantMap = new HashMap<>();
   
  initalMap.forEach((id, object) -> {
      Code code = repository.getCodeById(id);
      giantMap.computeIfAbsent(code, ignore -> new ArrayList<>())
                        .add(object);
   });
```

Comment: What is `List<String, Object>`?  `List` is a container of objects of _one_ type.  What is `ObjectOne` -- a class or an instance of a class?  Where does it come from?

Comment: I don’t understand the problem. As far as I can see, your `forEach` code is equivalent to `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> giantMap = initalMap.entrySet().stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> repository.getCodeById(e.getKey()), Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))`. You already named the relevant pointers, `Collectors.groupingBy()` and `Collectors.mapping()`, and their use for this task is rather straight-forward. But it won’t work with your incompatible types, the same way as your `forEach` approach can’t actually work as long as you don’t fix them.

Comment: I indeed had a typo in my question, it had to be List<Map<String, Object>>. The object itself contains a Map<LocalDate, Object>

Comment: It sounds like you want a [`Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's assume there is a map of some ids to objects of type `ObjectOne`: `Map<ID, ObjectOne>`.

The key IDs are converted to some `Code` type by a database call, and the `ObjectOne` values of the first map are just collected into another map using `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping` as intended initially:

```java
Map<ID, ObjectOne> initialMap = ...;

Map<Code, List<ObjectOne>> mapByCode = initialMap
        .entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<ID, ObjectOne>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> repository.getCodeById(e.getKey()),
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

Also, a `keySet` of the initial map may be iterated upon:

```java
// or using keySet()
Map<Code, List<ObjectOne>> mapByCode2 = initialMap
        .keySet()
        .stream() // Stream<ID>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            repository::getCodeById,
            Collectors.mapping(initialMap::get, Collectors.toList())
        ));
```